# Help determining a meromorphic function satisfying certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm actually sitting in my university's library with a complex analysis textbook next to me, but I think I don't even know what to look for in it. The question is:

> Use Liouville's theorem to determine the meromorphic function $f$
>   satisfying
>
> 1. $f$ has a pole of order 3 in $z = 0$, simple poles in $z = i$ and $z = -i$, and holomorphic otherwise
> 2. $zf(z) \rightarrow 1$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$
> 3. $f$ is an odd function
> 4. The Laurent series corresponding to $f$ with convergence ring $K = \{z \in \mathbf{C} |\:|z| > 1\}$ has coefficients $(c_n)$ satisfying $c_{-1} =
>     -1$ and $c_{-5} = 2$.

Number one is not a problem, however I don't understand how to get number two, even with the solution available to me:

> From 2., we see that $zf(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z^2(z-i)(z+i)} \rightarrow
> > 1$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$. In particular, there is some $R_0 > 0$
>   for which $$ |\frac{g(z)}{z^2(z-i)(z+i)}| \leq 2 $$ for all $|z| \geq
>  R_0$, and consequently, $|g(z)| \leq 4|z|^4$ for all $|z| \geq R_1$,
>   for some $R_1 >0$. Liouville's theorem then says that $g(z) = a_0 +
>  a_1z + a_2z^2 + a_3z^3 + a_4z^4$ with $a_i \in \mathbf{C}$.

What I don't understand is where that $2$ comes from, and then how it becomes $4|z|^4$ later on. If I multiply out the denominator I get $|z^4+z^2|$. I think it has something to do with the triangle inequality, but I can't think of anything else after that when it comes to the second criterion. I can do the other ones though.

I hope my formatting is alright, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $2$ could be replaced by $1+\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0.$  All he's saying is that in some neighborhood of $\infty,\ zf(z)$ is as close to $1$ as you like.

As to the $4$, we have $$|g(z)|\le 2|z^4+z^2|\le2(|z^4|+|z^2|)\le2(|z^4|+|z^4|), |z|\ge1$$